# How can I convert csv to List with Java 8?

Tags: list, java-8

I want to get either empty list or list of strings from CSV. And I tried below approach:

```
String valueStr = "US,UK";
List<String> countryCodes = StringUtils.isBlank(valueStr)
                                    ? Collections.emptyList()
                                    : Arrays.stream(valueStr.split(DELIMITER))
                                            .map(String::trim)
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I make it more concise without ternary operator, keeping it easy as well? This works fine. Just checking other approaches.

Comment: Is this just a 1-record csv document?

Comment: you mean single line? then, yes!

Comment: Try something like this : `Optional.ofNullable(valueStr)
                .map(s->Arrays.stream(s.split(DELIMITER))
                        .map(String::trim)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())).orElse(Collections.emptyList());`

Answer (score 1):

You can filter:

```
List<String> countryCodes = Arrays.stream(
            StringUtils.trimToEmpty(valueStr).split(DELIMITER))
        .filter(v -> !v.trim().isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above returns an empty list when tested with a blank. It also excludes blank values (such as the last value from `"UK,"`)

Answer (score 1):

```
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile(DELIMITER);

public static List<String> getIt(String valueStr) {

    return Optional.ofNullable(valueStr)
                   .map(p::splitAsStream)
                   .map(x -> x.map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                   .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
}
```